# Replace unicode characters in filename?

Tags: php, file, unicode, unicode-string

I am using an upload form which returns uploaded files on the following form:

> ["http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/120-311e1865ce18d60a3e14cd555669bfa5/2016/11/Sk\u00e6rmbillede-2016-11-27-kl.-10.17.0431.png","http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/120-311e1865ce18d60a3e14cd555669bfa5/2016/11/Sk\u00e6rmbillede-2016-11-27-kl.-15.46.5425.png"]

I would like to remove all brackets, backslashes and quotes, which I am successfully doing with `str_replace`. However, '\u00e6' is unicode for the special character 'æ'.

How can I replace all unicode characters like that with their corresponding special chars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a [JSON](http://json.org/) encoded array.

Use the [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to convert it to a PHP array. The Unicode escapes will be dealt with as well.